# NSURLSession authentication and downloading file in background

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

In iPad app, I need to connect to a server and download files that's using a self-signed SSL certificate with `NSURLSession` object in background mode:

```
static NSString *const URL = @"https://...";

- (void)testBackgroundDownloadTask {
    if (self.downloadTask) {
        return self;
    }
    self.session = [self backgroundSession];
    NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL];
    self.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
    [self.downloadTask resume];
}

- (NSURLSession *)backgroundSession{
    static NSURLSession *sess = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:URL];
        // Default configuration: working perfectly
        //NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    configuration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = YES;
    //configuration.TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol = kSSLProtocolAll;
    configuration.networkServiceType = NSURLNetworkServiceTypeBackground;
        sess = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    });
    return sess;
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {
    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = challenge.protectionSpace;
    NSString *authMethod = protectionSpace.authenticationMethod;

    if ([authMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate]) {
        // obtain challenge, it working with NSURLSession in default session config 
        [self.challengeHandler handleChallenge:challenge onCompletion:^(id obj) {
            NSURLCredential *c = (NSURLCredential *)obj;
            if (c) {
                [challenge.sender useCredential:c forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
                completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, c);
            }
            else {
                [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            }
        }];
    }
    else if ([authMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
    }
}
```

If I use `defaultSessionConfiguration`, my app after call `didReceiveChallenge` method perform successfully download file (call `NSURLSesionDownloadDelegate` methods

```
– URLSession:downloadTask:didResumeAtOffset:expectedTotalBytes: 
– URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite: 
– URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:
```

But I use `backgroundSessionConfiguration`, after call `didReceiveChallenge` other delegate’s methods not called (file not downloading and `didCompleteWithError` not called)
Any ideas on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: This is currently unavailable.  There is some discussion on the Apple Developer Forums that you can search for if you have a developer account.  It is recommended that you file a bug report with Apple with an explanation of how it's affecting your product. https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you testing this in the background?
2. On your `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`, you should see what you get when you implement

   ```
   - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session 
       task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task 
       didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
       NSLog(@"%s %@ %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, task.response, error);
   }
   ```
3. If any of that stuff in `–URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` is async, then you need to surround it with a `UIApplication`/`UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` {`begin`,`end`}`BackgroundTask...`, or iOS will kill your background process when the stack pops.